# Verse location in Brahmanda Puran

Tags: puranas, madhvacharya

> tribhAShAM yo na jAnAti rItInAM shatameva cha vyatyAsAdIn sapta bhEdAn
> vedAdyarthaM tu yo vadet.h |
>  sa yAti nirayaM
> ghoramanyathAj-nAnasambhavam.h ||

The above verses are said to be mentioned in the Brahmanda Purana.
Can any one tell the exact location of the above verses in the Brahmanda Purana?

Comment: Are saying that these verses are in Brahmanda Purana or asking whether they are found in Brahmanda Purana or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://mahabharata-resources.org/mbtntrans/chapter_9_gururajahrao.pdf check out 138-139 verse same shloka is present. But this verse is not from brahmanda puran. http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/corpustei/sa_brahmANDapurANa.xml here IAST transliteration of this purana is present, no verse is there as such.

How I came to this conclusion - The verse you provided is in harvard kyoto https://www.ashtangayoga.info/philosophy/sanskrit-and-devanagari/transliteration-tool/#hk/iast/  here you can convert into IAST , and in the link of brahmanda purana click command +F , you can type this verse and no result will come.